# Passing by rvalue does not destroy object

Tags: c++11, c++14

I'm a bit new to move semantics in C++ and trying to understand it better. I came across some code in which a function takes a rvalue to a move-only type (unique_ptr). So I decided to experiment for myself.

I defined a function that takes as parameter a rvalue to a unique_ptr like this:

```
void print(std::unique_ptr<Car>&& car)
{
    std::cout << "Car" << car->Get() << std::endl;
}
```

The class Car is a simple class:

```
class Car
{
public:
    Car(int i) : N(i) { std::cout << "Car" << N << std::endl; }
    ~Car() { std::cout << "~Car" << N << std::endl; }

    int Get() { return N;  }

private:
    int N;
};
```

Now if I call the function like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Car> car = std::make_unique<Car>(99);
print(std::move(car));
```

I find that the car object is not destroyed after calling the print() function. Casting to an rvalue does not invoke a move constructor in this case.

However, if I change my function definition like so:

```
void print(std::unique_ptr<Car> car)
{
    std::cout << "Car" << car->Get() << std::endl;
}
```

Then the car object is no longer valid after calling print(). The parameter of print() is a proper sink parameter.

This is quite interesting since everything I've read says that you should expect an object to be destroyed after using std::move - i.e. its internal resources are no longer valid.

I would be grateful for some better explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first thing to remember is that `std::move` is misnamed. It does not ever move anything. It just makes it possible to move a thing by wrapping it in a special kind of reference.

The "move constructor" is the thing that does an actual move. `std::unique_ptr<T>(std::unique_ptr &&ref)`, for example.

Function parameters are copy or move constructed with a preference for move construction.

So, your first attempt just used it as a reference and never moved anything. You could have the same effect with a regular reference (a single `&`).

The second one does a proper move and after the call `car` will be `nullptr` inside the unique ptr. And `car` will destruct at the end of `print`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I agree that in the first case I might as well use a regular reference (&). Would there ever be a case for passing by rvalue?